# Searching multiple SQL tables for data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

In my SQL database I have a table for every state in the USA. The user can create multiple pages in different states. Each table has a "UserID" column that will always match the logged in user. How do I search multiple tables for the "UserID"?

```
string sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM[all tables] WHERE @UserID ='" + userID.Text + "'";

SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn1);
SqlDataReader DR1 = comm1.ExecuteReader();
if (DR1.Read())
{
Textbox1.Text = DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Two things, first of all I would suggest prepared statements over string concatenation as a method of preparing your sql command. Second, I don't know what RDBMS you're using but you're going to need some notion of JOINs this is not a C# or asp.net question but a pure SQL one.

Comment: can't you use a cursor for that?

Comment: fist question I will ask because I see the `GetValue(0).ToString()` call is what flavor of the database are you using..? is this SQLite? or Sql Server.., etc..? also you need to do your gathering and storage, into a List or other type of Collection.. I worked helping someone earlier using the GetValue() method and this yields errors just a heads up ..

Comment: Does all the tables have same columns?

Comment: Second thing that I have noticed is that why are you doing a `Select *` when all you are looking for is the userId, also where are you creating the `comm1.Parameters.AddWithValues("@UserID", userId.Text)` which by the way you should use a property and have proper validation otherwise you are setting yourself up for sql injection. `The way the code / query stands I doubt that you will get the intended results`

Comment: This is in SQL Server 2008. All of the state tables have the same columns. The only reason they are separate is to make it easier to archive later.
DJ Kraze- I created the pages on a different form so all of the data is in place. When you say proper validation do You mean the comm.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11);
comm.SelectCommand.Parameters["@au_id"].Value = UserID.Text;?

Comment: This is a situation that BEGS for normalization. Please consider it. PLEASE. The thought of fifty identical tables for state-related data makes tears of blood run from my eyes. You are already seeing the pains of dealing with non-normalized data for what should be very VERY simple and is easily avoided.

Comment: I am very new to databases. I've always thought having so many tables would be a pain down the road. Can one table really hold 10,000+ entries?

Comment: @user1599813 The rows (afaik) are limited by the amount of available storage space, but think about it this way: you can have a 64 bit integer as the primary key of a table, and the range of a 64 bit integer is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. That's a lot of rows.

Comment: For some perspective, I've worked on a (mostly normalized) database of ~10 'main' tables - several are over 100,000,000 rows.  Depending on available system resources, 10k rows might be kept in **RAM**, never mind actual storage.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't seen your database schema, but I can already tell you need to refactor it. There's no need to have a table for each state, and the maintenance on that could be rough. What you should have is a table holding all of the states, and then another table with a reference to the State table that holds whatever information you want (your "pages")

```
CREATE TABLE States
(
    StateID int not null, --PK
    StateName nvarchar(32) not null
)

CREATE TABLE Pages
(
    PagesID int not null, --PK
    StateID int not null, --FK
    UserID int not null
    //Whatever other columns you need
)
```

Now, you can query the `Pages` table based on a specific `Page`, `State` or `User`

```
SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE UserID = (userId)
SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE StateID IN (1, 5, 20)
SELECT * FROM Pages WHERE PageID = (pageID)
```

Comment: So if I make a new table for the Page information, will one table be enough to hold over 10,000 entries? Also my other issue is the UserID is the primary key so how would I get multiple entries from the same User into the same table? Would I need to change my primary key to something else?

Comment: I'll be able to give you more of an answer when I get home in an hour, but I'd create a `User` table, a `Page` table and a `State` table. Page would have a foreign key to `User` and `State`. If you read my comment to your question, yes, a single table can hold many, many more rows than 10,000. You'll want to look into `indexes` and performance optimizations, but that shouldn't be a huge concern right this second.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is that you need to change your database so that all this information is held in a single table.  The easy answer is to take a few minutes to create a view that unions all the tables together so that you can access them as if they were all in one table.

The only difference in my answer from the others though is that I wouldn't union them in your c# code.  I would just create an actual view on the database that unions them all together.  The view will be simple (though long) and your code will be simple.

Comment: Clarification:  I meant all the states should be in one table... didn't mean everything should be in one table.  Refer to Dave's answer for what the tables should look like.

Answer (score 0):

If tables have the same columns I would go for something like. Using the sql `UNION`.

```
var statesTables = new[]{"NY, Texas, Oregano, Alabama}";

var qBuild = new StringBuilder();

qBuild.Append(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE UserId = @userId ", statesTables[0]));

for(int i=1;i<stateTables.Length;i++){
     qbuild.Append(string.Format("UNION SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE UserId = @userId ", statesTables[i]))
}

SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(qBuild.ToString(), conn1);
comm1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("userId", userId));
```

It will generate SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM NY WHERE UserId = @userId
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Texas WHERE UserId = @userId
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Oregano WHERE UserId = @userId
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Alabama WHERE UserId = @userId
```

*If there are some different columns, replace * with column names tables have in common.*

**BUT, as other suggests, refactoring your DB schema would be the best!**